# Safely stopping PGReplicationStream

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

this is more of a java concurrency question then a PG question.

I have a worker that reads a PGReplication stream.

```
    while (true) {
      ByteBuffer msg = stream.read();
      // ...
    }
```

I want to be able to let callers stop this worker. I thought what I could do was to return the `stream`, and let a caller call "close".

```
// someone calls
stream.close()
// worker stops
```

This would work, but then the worker would throw an error. I don't really think I would be able to differentiate here though between a legitimate error (something happened and stream closed), vs intended behavior (caller wanted to unsubscribe).

How could I achieve this behavior?

I could for example keep my own `stopped` boolean, and use `readPending` instead of `read`. Here I would have to do my own loop, and poll every 10ms or so. In that case, what would be the tradeoff for performance with `read` vs `readPending`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, the `PGReplicationStream`'s `.read` does not respond to an InterruptedException.

You can either use `.readPending`, or the `thread interruptor` will need to be smarter, and close the stream before interrupting the thread.